# Python smtplib - No recipient after sending mail

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I recently wrote a script that sent me an email if a website I wanted to monitor had changed using smtplib. The program works, and I get the email but when I look at the sent email (as I am sending myself the email from the same account), it says that there is no recipient or 'To:' address, only a Bcc with the address I want the email to be sent to. Is this a feature of smtplib -- that it doesn't actually add a 'To:' address, only Bcc addresses? code is as follows:

```
if (old_source != new_source):

# now we create a mesasge to send via email
fromAddr = "example@gmail.com"
toAddr = "example@gmail.com"
msg = ""

# smtp login
username = "example@gmail.com"
pswd = "password"

# create server object and login to the gmail smtp
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server.login(username, pswd)
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example `-> # Add the From: and To: headers at the start!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your code as follows will do the trick:

```
if (old_source != new_source):

# now we create a mesasge to send via email
fromAddr = "example@gmail.com"
toAddr = "example@gmail.com"
msg = ""

# smtp login
username = "example@gmail.com"
pswd = "password"

# create server object and login to the gmail smtp

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
header = 'To:' + toAddr + '\n' + 'From: ' + fromAddr + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
msg = header + msg
server.login(username, pswd)
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: ok, so since the message lacked any headers, smtplib's sendmail() automatically put the second address passed in as bcc you think?

Comment: Yes, I think that must be the default behaviour. I have always just included the headers in the message, and have therefore never come across your issue until now.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually adding any headers to your message, separated from the body by a blank line e.g.:

```
...
msg="""From: sender@domain.org
To: recipient@otherdomain.org
Subject: Test mail

Mail body, ..."""
...
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for the reply, just had to add those headers

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems to work for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#from smtplib import SMTP # Standard connection
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP #SSL connection
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

sender = 'example@gmail.com'
receivers = ['example@gmail.com']


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'example@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'example@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email via python test 1'
message = 'This is the body of the email line 1\nLine 2\nEnd'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

ServerConnect = False
try:
    smtp_server = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com','465')
    smtp_server.login('#####@gmail.com', '############')
    ServerConnect = True
except SMTPHeloError as e:
    print "Server did not reply"
except SMTPAuthenticationError as e:
    print "Incorrect username/password combination"
except SMTPException as e:
    print "Authentication failed"

if ServerConnect == True:
    try:
        smtp_server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except SMTPException as e:
        print "Error: unable to send email", e
    finally:
        smtp_server.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing it out there: please try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer, but I feel like it can help everyone out!

It really provides a lot of defaults: I'm quite sure you'll be able to send an email directly with:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send(to_addrs, contents = msg)
```

Which will also set the headers :)

You'll have to install `yagmail` first with either:

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

Once you will want to also embed html/images or add attachments, you'll **really** love the package!

It will also make it a lot safer by preventing you from having to have your password in the code.